# Insert on each inner joined foreach row matched

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, lets called them A and B. Here is what they look like

Table A:

```
ID   BCODE 
1    A1 
2    B1  
3    C1  
4    D1  
5    F1
```

Table B:

```
X    Y    IDX  IDY
A1   D1  
D1   F1  
C1   B1
```

Table B has columns 'X' and 'Y' that have values that are found in Table A's column BCODE.

I want to insert the ID from Table A for each joined X,Y column with Table A's BCODE. Each matching BCODE for X goes to IDX. Each matching BCODE for Y goes to IDY. This is what it should look like

Table B:

```
X    Y    IDX  IDY
A1   D1    1    4
D1   F1    4    5
C1   B1    3    2
```

I have a table A and B with about 50 million rows in both Table A and B

Does anyone know how I can do this ? I tried using INNER JOINS but it didnt populate all the columns. Thanks

Comment: which database you are using? As you have tagged all.

Comment: Please tag your question with *one* database tag -- the one you are using.  Also, show the code that you have attempted.  I'm removing all the database tags except SQL.

Comment: sorry, this is with Mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a simple `join` with the `Update` command:

---

in **MS SQL Server**:

```
Update tableB
set
   tableB.IDX=a.ID,
   tableB.IDY=aa.ID
from 
tableB
join tableA a on tableB.X=a.BCODE
join tableA aa on tableB.Y=aa.BCODE
```

---

in **MySQL**:

```
Update tableB
join tableA a on tableB.X=a.BCODE
join tableA aa on tableB.Y=aa.BCODE
set
   tableB.IDX=a.ID,
   tableB.IDY=aa.ID
```

(**Edit:** as question is about MySQL I just create [The DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7669e/1) for it)

---

in **Oracle PL/SQL**:

```
Update (select tableB.IDX idx, tableB.IDY idy, a.ID ida, aa.ID idaa
from tableB
join tableA a on tableB.X=a.BCODE
join tableA aa on tableB.Y=aa.BCODE)
set
   idx=ida,
   idy=idaa
```

Comment: Thanks, will try it out today !

Comment: Didnt work. I can see the rows  in each table. Not sure why it didnt work

Comment: @AriesOnTheCusp, you are welcome, it works very well, [just tested it here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7669e/1), see it

Comment: I realized why its not working for me, and fixed the problem. If one of the columns fails to match on the join then the other , even if it matches wont be written to the update. Thanks for providing the SQLFiddle, that was key for me to understand the error (sorry, I'm a SQL newbie). I had to break the update into separate statements to get any results to show up. It took 1 hour 36 min for both updates in my database ! Maybe I should add an index. Thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE b
   SET idx =
          (SELECT id
             FROM a
            WHERE bcode = b.x),
       idy =
          (SELECT id
             FROM a
            WHERE bcode = b.y);
```

Comment: As this question at fist was tagget "Oracle" I didn't state the RDBMS. My answer works on Oracle 11.2.0.3 (at least).

Comment: Thanks Jon, I appreciate your answer ! Sorry, about the wrong tag !